# Changing the LFS size detection in Sourcetree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Is it possible to change the file detection of 2MB to something larger? Github allows up to 50MB files so I would like this error to appear for files larger than that.

I tried tools > Options > Dif but those values don't seem to change anything.

Is this a Sourcetree thing or a Git thing?

Thanks

[image]